# Arrange 8 plots and a legend in a grid

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, gridextra, cowplot

I have 8 plots and one legend that I would like to arrange in a 3x3 grid, so that the axes all align.

It works perfectly fine when I am not including the legend to my grid, but as soon as I have added the legend, my plots get shifted and are no longer aligned.

```
plot_grid(SiO2TiO2, SiO2Al2O3, SiO2FeO, SiO2MgO, SiO2CaO, SiO2Na2O, SiO2K2O, SiO2P2O5, align=c("hv"),nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
```

Plots aligned in a 3x3 grid without legend:
[image]

```
plot_grid(SiO2TiO2, SiO2Al2O3, SiO2FeO, SiO2MgO, SiO2CaO, SiO2Na2O, SiO2K2O, SiO2P2O5, legend, align=c("hv"),nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
```

> Warning messages:
>
> 1: In align_plots(plotlist = plots, align = align) :
>     Graphs cannot be vertically aligned. Placing graphs unaligned.
>
> 2: In align_plots(plotlist = plots, align = align) :
>     Graphs cannot be horizontally aligned. Placing graphs unaligned.

Plots not aligned in a 3x3 grid with legend:
[image]

Anyone know how to align the legend with the plots?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to define the width of your plots in grid.arrange command.

Like in the following example:

```
plot_grid(SiO2TiO2, SiO2Al2O3, SiO2FeO, SiO2MgO, SiO2CaO, SiO2Na2O, SiO2K2O, SiO2P2O5, legend, align=c("hv"), nrow = 3, ncol = 3, widths=c(2.3, 2.3, 2.3))
```

Comment: Hi! When I try your example, I get the following error and no plot: > Error in ggplot_to_gtable(x) : 
  Argument needs to be of class "ggplot" or "gtable"

Comment: Hi valz! Sorry for not responding, I didn't get a notification of a new post. 

I bypassed my issue with plotting 9 diagrams instead of 8, and putting the legend below those 9 plots

(i.e. I created one grid with 3x3 plots, then created another grid with two rows, 1 column, where my first plot was the 3x3 grid, and the secon plot is the legend)